# Getting "ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: email_confirmation" Error with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am running into this error when running my tests. I have checked to make sure all the `email_confirmation`s are spelled correctly and (unless I am crazy) they are. I'm a bit of a Rails noob, so it could be something simple.

User Model

```ruby
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :email_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name,
                  :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

  validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 25 }
  validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 25 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :email_confirmation, presence: true
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { maximum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

Rspec tests

```ruby
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  before { @user = User.new(email: "user@example.com",
                            first_name: "John", last_name: "Smith",
                            password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar",
                            email_confirmation: "user@example.com") }

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:first_name) }
  it { should respond_to(:last_name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:email_confirmation) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should respond_to(:password) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
  it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when first name is not present" do
    before { @user.first_name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when last name is not present" do
    before { @user.last_name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = @user.email_confirmation = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password is not present" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when first_name is too long" do
    before { @user.first_name = "a" * 26 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when last_name is too long" do
    before { @user.last_name = "a" * 26 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.
                             foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        @user.should_not be_valid
     end      
    end
  end

  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address
        @user.should be_valid
      end      
    end
  end

  describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
      user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email doesn't match confirmation" do
    before { @user.email_confirmation = "mismatch@example.com" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password confirmation is nil" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email confirmation is nil" do
    before { @user.email_confirmation = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "with a password that's too short" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 }
    it { should be_invalid }
  end

  describe "return value of authenticate method" do
    before { @user.save }
    let(:found_user) { User.find_by_email(@user.email) }

    describe "with valid password" do
      it { should == found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
    end

    describe "with invalid password" do
      let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

      it { should_not == user_for_invalid_password }
      specify { user_for_invalid_password.should be_false }
    end
  end
end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130417021135) do

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
    t.string   "password_digest"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true

end
```

Comment: Can you paste your DB schema for the table that backs this model?

Comment: Edited the post with it

Comment: Thanks. Rails has support for confirmation validation built-in, see suggestion below.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're getting `UnknownAttributeError` because you don't have a column in your `users` table called `email_confirmation`. By default, ActiveRecord will look for DB columns named the same as the attributes you use to construct the model, but this line is trying to construct a User with an attribute the database doesn't know about:

```
  before { @user = User.new(email: "user@example.com",
                        first_name: "John", last_name: "Smith",
                        password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar",
                        email_confirmation: "user@example.com") }
```

Are you really intending to save the email confirmation in the database, or are you just wanting to check that it matches email before saving it? I assume the latter, and Rails actually has built-in support for doing just that:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, :confirmation => true
  validates :email_confirmation, :presence => true
end
```

See more details on the [Rails Guide to Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#confirmation), or the [`validates_confirmation_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_confirmation_of) API docs. (And you'll probably need to do the same thing for `:password_confirmation`.)

Comment: I had the same issue. DB schema was the problem (I thought it was the migration). Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes migration is not yet done on specific environment. Issue command like `rake RAILS_ENV=production db:migrate` solves the problem.

Comment: If you modified the schema you can also try deleting the cookies

Answer (score 30):

Having just spent a ton of time debugging my own instance of this, I thought I would chime in with a third possibility.

I had done a migration correctly and verified it by inspecting my `ActiveRecord` in the rails console. I had tried recreating my db from the schema many times and I had tried re-running the migration many times, all to no avail.

The problem, in my case, is that I was seeing the problem when running my unit tests, not at runtime. The issue is that my test database had gotten out of sync in my migration/rollback testing. The solution was quite simple. All I had to do was reset the test database with:

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

Comment: Good catch. My case was a little different. I had SQL schema format in Rails 5.0.0.1 and I did db:rollback once and db:migrate again. Between the rollback and the migrate I modified the last db migration file. As documented in http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-existing-migrations this pattern is not recommended but could be handy in early development. I don't really know how or why but the generated structure.sql schema was the issue for me and I had to delete it and run db:migrate again.

Comment: This was a great addition to the answer. Worked as advertised!

Comment: This kept failing for me until I specified the environment to be test `rake db:test:prepare RAILS_ENV=test`

Answer (score 11):

I understand that the answer above is marked correct and solves the OP's problem. But there is another cause for this error that goes unheeded in a number of stackoverflow posts on this topic. This error can occur in a polymorphic many to many when you forget to use the as: option to a has_many. For example:

```
class AProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profile_students
  has_many :students, through: :profile_students
end

class BProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profile_students
  has_many :students, through: :profile_students
end

class ProfileStudent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile, polymorphic: :true
  belongs_to :student
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profile_students
  has_many :aprofiles, through: :profile_students
  has_many :bprofiles, through: :profile_students
end
```

This will give you this error:

```
Getting “ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: profile_id
```

when you try to do the following:

```
a = AProfile.new
a.students << Student.new
```

The solution is to add the :as option to AProfile and BProfile:

```
class AProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profile_students, as: :profile
  has_many :students, through: :profile_students
end

class BProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profile_students, as: :profile
  has_many :students, through: :profile_students
end
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and this worked like magic. Add this line at the end of your migration statements for each model you would update. Resets all the cached information about columns, which will cause them to be reloaded on the next request.

```
    <ModelName>.reset_column_information
```

Reference : https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/reset_column_information/class

Answer (score 0):

I have the same message error and I fix ordering the params as same order of columns definition in database:

> CONTROLLER

```
def create
    worktime = Worktime.create(name: params[:name], workhours: params[:workhours], organization: @organization, workdays: params[:workdays])

    render json: worktime
end
```

> DATABASE

```
Table: worktimes
Columns:
id  int(11) AI PK
name    varchar(255)
workhours   text
organization_id int(11)
workdays    text
```

Comment: I am 99.999% sure that whatever problem you had, it was not solved by putting the parameters in a specific order. If it was then something else was at play.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error plenty of times when a table didn't have the column, but I had strange cause this time. For some reason, my migrations were perfect, but (weirdly) `schema.rb` hadn't updated, so `rake db:migrate db:seed` didn't create the column. I have no idea why that happened.

TL;DR, if your migrations are up to date, check `schema.rb` and make sure it is too